# Apple Map Shows small branches on route

Tags: ios, swift, routes, apple-maps, mkdirection

[image]I am drawing a line on map to make custom route between those points. SO for this I divide my coordinates array into chunks and make multiple calls for MKDirections. So i have multiple source and destinations to calculate route and add polylines on map. But I am facing issue of small branches alongside of road, Anyone has faced this issue?
I want to remove this branch which is going out on other road.